# How to access GNURoot Debian executables from outside the app?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, command-line, ssh, python

I've just setup GNURoot Debian and I could install Python 2.7.
However, I'd like to run Python 2.7 outside of the GNURoot Debian Terminal Window.
For example, if I ssh into the device, I'd like to be able to simply run Python.

Here's what I've naively tried so far:

```
root@odroidc2:/data/data/com.gnuroot.debian/debian/usr/bin # ls python*
python     python2    python2.7
root@odroidc2:/data/data/com.gnuroot.debian/debian/usr/bin # ./python2
sh: ./python2: No such file or directory
```

Any hints on how I can use Python 2.7 via ssh ?

Comment: You can't usually execute anything from the data partition.  You could try copying them to `/system/xbin/` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. I've tried creating a symbolic link, but I get a Read-only file system error:
```
ln -s /data/data/com.gnuroot.debian/debian/usr/bin/python /system/xbin/python                                                                                         
ln: /system/xbin/python: Read-only file system
```
Any tips on how I could get around this ?

Comment: `mount -o remount,rw /system`.  Must be done as root.  I'm not sure if a symlink will work but it's worth a try.